# Parameter query on nvarchar(max) shows as ntext error

Tags: sql-server-2008, parameters, ntext

I recently converted all ntext column types in my database to nvarchar(max).
I then ran EXECUTE sp_refreshview for the related views.

Yet when I run the following Parameter query (from classic ASP) on a view, I get an error:
    Query:

```
SELECT   CARID 
FROM     vwCAR 
WHERE    (1=1) 
AND      (Description LIKE '%'+ ? + '%') 
ORDER BY CARID;
```

> Error: The data types nvarchar and ntext are incompatible in the add operator   (yet there are no longer any ntext columns!)

Yet I do NOT get this error if I run the same query directly SQL Server without the ? parameter as:
    Query:

```
SELECT  CARID 
FROM    vwCAR 
WHERE   (1=1) 
AND     (Description LIKE '%test%') 
ORDER BY CARID;
```

I tried using Convert in the query, but had same result:
    Query:

```
SELECT   CARID 
FROM     vwCAR 
WHERE    (1=1) 
AND      (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Description) LIKE N'%'+ ? + '%') 
ORDER BY CARID;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additional information:
I changed the type to nVarChar(4000) instead of (MAX) and everything works fine.  This is a work around, but it solved the problem.

Just so I will know for the future, is it possible to run a parameter query using LIKE criteria on a nVarChar(Max) type column?

(Thank you @McNets for the post clean up .. I am new to this)

Comment: You can add an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong field type adLongVarWChar (203) in the parameter. Should have been using adVarWChar (202) for the nvarchar(max) type.

Confusion arose when I retrieved the field type directly from the database as noted below, it returned 203 for the nvarchar(max) type, so I assumed setting the parameter based on that type would work.
`For each ofield in objRS.Fields
    Redim Preserve FieldTypes(1,x)
    FieldTypes(0,x) = ofield.type
    FieldTypes(1,x) = ofield.definedsize
    x = x + 1
Next`

Answer (score 0):

try to set before :

Set @value = '%' + @value + '%' ;

then use:

(description like @value )